# Why isn't Node.js Express with MongoDB responding to fetch API calls (ReactJS and Redux)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, reactjs

Using ReactJS, Redux, Webpack, Node.js and Express with MongoDB, I am following the tutorial https://github.com/vasansr/mern-es6 and trying to integrate it into my project. First, I am trying to make a POST request to the server I created. And it gets a response with a success and no error is logged. Yet inside the server POST API, it does not log `console.log('Req body', req.body);`, and in terminal I checked to see if the database has been created with `mongo -> show dbs` but it is empty.

Could it be that something is intercepting the request from the server? What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This...

```
app.use('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve('client/index.html'));
});
```

comes before:

```
app.post('/api/users/', function(req, res) {
  //...
});
```

Since it's `app.use` the `POST /api/users` will still hit that middleware, and `res.sendFile` ends the request/response. You'll probably see that your post is getting back the client HTML.

Try moving your client HTML endpoint to the *end* of your middleware, just before the error handlers if you have them. That way, it'll only get used if none of your API endpoints match. Or if you want just `GET /` to return the HTML, change `use` to `get`:

```
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {noInfo: true, publicPath: config.output.publicPath}));

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

app.use(express.static('dist')); //where bundle.js is

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/api/users/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('Req body', req.body);
  var newUser = req.body;
  db.collection('users').insertOne(newUser, function(err, result) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    var newId = result.insertedId;

    db.collection('users').find({_id: newId}).next(function(err, doc) {
      if(err) console.log(err);
      res.json(doc);
    });
  });
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve('client/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: appreciate the response! could you show an example to what you advised? can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Sure, just updated. Basically, change the order of the middleware; express sequentially goes through each middleware until there is an error or the response is ended. The difference between `app.use` and `app.get` or `app.post` is that the former is saying "call this middleware for anything under `/`, and the others are saying "call this middleware when this URL & method matches"

Comment: Really appreciate it!!!! Finally worked!!! Accepted the answer. Sorry but could you clarify on what it means by under `/`?

Comment: Meaning the URL starts with `/`, so in this case `app.use('/', middleware)` is a bit redundant. But it's helpful if you want to, say, apply a middleware for all requests prefixed with `/api`.

Comment: Ah gotcha really appreciate the clarification! One last question, now that I am able to get users to register and store their credentials in the database, I would like to do a session whenever they log in. Where should I start? Any guidance would be really helpful! Also how should I do the log in credential check also, to see if the entered credentials match the ones in the database? Thanks again Jacob!

Comment: Probably best to avoid extended discussion here, though I'd be happy to look at further questions if I can answer 'em.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122252/discussion-between-jo-ko-and-jacob).

Comment: please let me know if you get a chance!

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/api/users/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('Req body', req.body);
  var newUser = req.body;
  db.collection('users').insertOne(newUser, function(err, result) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    var newId = result.insertedId;

    db.collection('users').find({_id: newId}).next(function(err, doc) {
      if(err) console.log(err);
      res.json(doc);
    });
  });
});
```

I have a small comments about this code, for `if(err) console.log(err);` i think you should change to `if(err) return console.log(err);`.

For `error` case, i think you need `return`, otherwise the below part will be excuted, and there will report some error.